# XSL getting out of context using dynamic XPATH

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to reformat an XML I get from an appliance into an HTML table, and it's format is not usual.

It use unique references in node name's, like this:

**/network/content/host/content/REF_1/content**
**/network/content/network/content/REF_2/content**

and then, it use the same references to another part of the file, as a value of a content node, like this:

**/rules/content/rules/content/REF_3/content/sources/content/name = REF_1**
**/rules/content/rules/content/REF_3/content/destinations/content/name = REF_2**

I'm trying to write a template for content that instead of getting me REF_ID which is unique, I try to get the name, in the other branch leaf. this mean I'm trying to find a value that is out of my actual context.

I'm able to retrieve the name XPATH using this variable:

```
<xsl:variable name='objName' select="concat('/storage/objects/',@linkclass,'/content/',@linktype,'/content/',current(),'/content/name/content')" />
```

but, I'm not able to use this XPATH in a query like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="{$objName}">
```

I suppose this doesn't work because it's out of context but when I ask statically for one of those XPATH I get the value.

My full code is not very complicated:

```
<xsl:template match="content">

<xsl:variable name='objXPATH' select="concat('/storage/objects/',@linkclass,'/content/',@linktype,'/content/',current(),'/content/name/content')" />
<xsl:variable name='obj' select="{$objXPATH}" />

<xsl:element name="a">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
#<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:value-of select="$obj"/>

<br />
</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

I need help to fix this, I'm on it since one day with no evolution, and it's driving me crazy. I'm more like a script kiddie than a real developer.

Comment: This is "dynamic evaluation" which is not possible in pure XSLT 1.0, or XSLT 2.0, although there are extension functions that support it. However, it may not be the best approach here. Can you post a sample of the XML you are actually using (rather than just an xpath expression) and the output you expect to generate, as then another approach could be proposed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic evaluation (treating a string in a variable as an XPath expression and evaluating it) is available as a vendor extension in a number of XSLT processors, and it becomes part of the standard with the introduction of xsl:evaluate in XSLT 3.0. If your XSLT processor doesn't have such an extension you may be able to write it yourself. Alternatively, if you explain the problem better, we may be able to suggest a solution that does not require dynamic evaluation.